# How to pick a crank puller?

Tags: maintenance, crankset, bottom-bracket

I need to get a crank puller for my square-taper spindle.  There are several available on eBay and Amazon.  What information do I need -- about the puller, my bottom bracket and my crankset -- to pick the right crank puller?

My spindle is a bolt-type square taper.

(Is there a wide variety of crank puller types -- meaning I need to be careful to pick the right one -- or will it be obvious just by looking at them which ones fit and which don't?)

Here's what I have, in pictures.

[image: crank exterior with ruler]
[image: crank exterior]
[image: crank and bottom bracket]
[image: crank with bolt removed]

Comment: As far as I know, they're all standard.

Comment: Several pullers are made with a reversible threaded dealie, so that two different thread sizes are accommodated.  These pullers cover the vast majority of square taper cranks.

Comment: I'm happy with the Topeak (though Park are of course highly regarded).  This did me for two different square taper bikes 20 years apart without hassle (you do need a *big* Allen key, if you haven't got one maybe get a puller that uses a spanner)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Nathan Knutsonsaid in response to a now-deleted answer:

> There are several older square taper crank with extractor thread sizes other than 22x1, and there are some older 22x1 pullers with tips that only work with nutted spindles.

The vast majority of cranks have a thread size of 22x1. There are other older crank sets that use different sizes (two others I can think of immediately), but these would only be on what would be considered vintage bikes today.

You need to ensure the tip of the puller is suited to the BB you have. Again, most modern Square tapers are pretty generic and its almost certain any generic puller will do the job.

Be careful about buying a cheaper extractor. I had one that came in a cheap bicycle tool kit that (unknown to me, first time I used one) was slightly undersized and stripped the tops off the threads of the crank. I purchased a Park puller and was able to remove the same crank with no problems.